# Unable to print date command inside heredoc in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to write a bash script to automatically print the date command but unfortunately, it is not working.

here is a snippet of the script... I have used 'EOF' as most suggested, but still not working.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat<<'EOF'>/etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo
[local]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - Base
baseurl=file:///home/user1/updates-$(date +%d%b%y)
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
EOF
```

Could someone help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't quote your here-document.  Quoting (any part of) the initial `EOF` marker will prevent the shell from performing any of the expansions in the document.  Since you *want* the shell to handle the command substitution around `date`, you need to leave the document unquoted.

If you want `$releasever` and `$basearch` left unexpanded, you will need to escape the `$` in front of it as shown here:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EOF >/etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo
[local]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux \$releasever - \$basearch - Base
baseurl=file:///home/user1/updates-$(date +%d%b%y)
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
EOF
```

Also note that this script is better executed by `/bin/sh` as it contains nothing `bash`-specific.

If the file that you are creating is a TOML file, you could also create it like so:

```bash
tomlq -n -t \
    --arg name 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - Base' \
    --arg baseurl "file:///home/user1/updates-$(date +%d%b%y)" \
    --argjson gpgcheck 0 \
    --argjson enabled 1 \
    '.local = $ARGS.named' >/etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo
```

This uses `tomlq` ([a TOML parser wrapper](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) around `jq`) and creates the TOML output

```
[local]
name = "Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - Base"
baseurl = "file:///home/user1/updates-29May22"
gpgcheck = 0
enabled = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, @kusalananda.. I just found that myself as well... thank you for your quick reply. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the answer... I have mistaken how to use the ''. So I modified the script as below.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat<<EOF>/etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo
[local]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux \$releasever - \$basearch - Base
baseurl=file:///home/user1/updates-$(date +%d%b%y)
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
EOF
```